# Async.fromBeginEnd with WinForms Begin/EndInvoke

Tags: .net, winforms, asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to write an Async wrapper on top of a function called listControls which extracts a list of Forms controls starting from a root control. The plan is to implement it in terms of Control.BeginInvoke, Control.EndInvoke and Async.FromBeginEnd

The code is below:

```
type private ListControls = delegate of unit -> Control list

let asyncListControls (root:Forms.Control) : Async<Control list> = 
    let beginInvoke (_, _) = 
        new ListControls(fun () -> listControls root)
        |> root.BeginInvoke

    let endInvoke result = 
        root.EndInvoke result :?> Control list

    Async.FromBeginEnd (beginInvoke, endInvoke)
```

The behavior that I'm getting is that the **endInvoke** is never executed. Anybody knows what am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

*EDIT*

Just to make it clear, this computation is executed eventually with Async.RunSynchronously.

Also if I replace this code with

```
/// code below is reproduced from memory and might not compile
let asyncListControls (root:Forms.Control) : Async<Control list> =
     let ctx = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current
     async {
         do! Async.SwitchToContext ctx
         return listControls root
         do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool ()
     }
```

...then it seems to work but I don't like it because of the forced context switches and the fact that the async computation is supposed to be built on the UI thread

Comment: Have you tried `asyncListControls root |> Async.RunSynchronously`?

Comment: Of course. I was only showing the code that builds the async computation. This is a computation which is composed in a bigger one.

Comment: You would be surprised at how often that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My underdstanding of the issue the following:

The async operation is executed with Async.RunSynchronously on the UI thread, which is blocking the thread.

During the execution, as it does Control.BeginInvoke it POSTs a message to the UI thread. This message cannot be processed because the UI thread is blocked on Async.RunSynchronously thus the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

`Async` is different from `Task` in that it doesn't start on creation.  As Daniel pointed out, you must explicitly start the `Async` using `Async.RunSynchronously` or some other method.